# How to handle accents or punctuations in xml in c# code

Tags: c#, dataset, special-characters

I am reading xml file by means of XmlReader and storing data in a c# DataSet. My XML file contains some accent characters as : ä, Ö etc. And also can contain any of the special characters. 
    I want the DataSet to store all this data and retrieve whenever required.
    When I read xml with such accent characters, it gives me an exception with message : "Invalid character in the given encoding". 
    Is there any way to deal with these characters without removing them from xml? Please help..
        Thanks in advance.

```
    Dataset data_set;
    xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("filepath"); 
    data_set.ReadXml(xmlFile);
```

Comment: The implication here is that your XML file is NOT using UTF8 encoding. Is that the case? (UTF8 is the default encoding used by XmlReader, but there's a Create() which lets you specify a stream, and you can set the correct encoding for that stream.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create and load the file with the same text encoding, preferably UTF-8. If you create the file "by hand" (e.g. with Notepad), it may be in a different encoding such as Windows-1252.